# Colors and Styles in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I am attempting to learn how to make Android apps(on Jellybean 4.1.2), but I have a problem with the style of my "HelloWorld" app.  What I'm going for looks like this(the default edit text/button look):

[image]

Unfortunately, what I have looks like this:

[image]

This is my layout file source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
         <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
         <Button
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/button_send" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I get it to look like that, and why wasn't it like that in the first place?

Thanks in advance,

Niro56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will just be targeting JellyBean then the code below should do the job. Just add this to your AndroidManifest.xml. When you have the manifest open, make sure you're looking at the xml code like this:

[image]

```
 <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
```

You should know that if you try to use the holo theme on a device that doesn't support it (aka: doesn't understand what Theme.Holo is) then it will most likely crash on those devices.

Comment: Regarding the last point (which might sound kind of scary to someone new to Android): if the app's minimum API level is at least 11 (platform 3.0+), then all devices on which it can run will support the holo theme, since that's built in as of 3.0. Alternatively, one can include something like [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) and not worry about compatibility (as far as the holo theme is concerned, that is).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the default android widgets and styles changed a lot from version to version. Especially from 2.3 to 3.0. The new Theme which was announced with HC is called the Holo Theme. Unfortunately you can not use this theme in previous versions(not without 3rd party libraries), therefore default widgets on GB and HC for example look pretty different. If you want to use this theme in previous versions there is a lib called [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere).

Besides that you should change your project build target to ICS or JB, then you can see your Layout in Holo Theme(even if you don't use HoloEverywhere):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done just by changing your theme in Android Manifest. Changing inside the Application applies to the entire application,but you can also change the themes for all the different activities in your application. Ex-

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AVST"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_avst" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
```